# COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog - how to get DCOM Config folder content?

Tags: windows, com, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to access DCOM Config via COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog?

I can get a collection of applications and configure them but cannot figure out how to get a collection of the items in the DCOM Config folder in Component Services.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they are presented visually in the same Windows tool (Component Services), the components in the "DCOM Config" and "COM+ Applications" are quite different.

COM+ Applications is accessible via API using the COM+ Catalog.

DCOM Config corresponds to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID reg key. There is a tool named DCOMPERM that allows to modify permissions as an example, see here (source included): http://www.myitforum.com/articles/11/view.asp?id=9323

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242178(VS.60).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206484/en

Comment: I found the tool. It's a Visual C++ 6.0 sample. I downloaded it a few weeks ago and compiled it and use it from a batch file now. But there must be a more proper solution, an API, possibly exposed to .NET...

Comment: I don't think you'll find something much better. This is all COM/OLE good ole' days plumbing. It's even older the the DCOM applications folder (component services). I don't see why this would be exposed to .NET. It's only there for compatibility/legacy reasons. Nobody would want to use DCOM today for new applications.